# -Xms: Initial heap size or minimum heap size?

Tags: java, memory, garbage-collection, jvm

`-Xms` is to specify initial heap size or minimum heap size?
I see differing viewpoints. Some like [second answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043817/java-xms-xmx-options-and-speed-trade-off), say that it is for initial heap and some others say that it is minimum heap size.

Or is it that the minimum size itself is the initial size?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The initial heap size is the minimum heap size. It won't get smaller than the initial heap size.

From [Tuning Garbage Collection with the 5.0 Java[tm] Virtual Machine](http://java.sun.com/docs/hotspot/gc5.0/gc_tuning_5.html#0.0.0.%20Total%20Heap|outline):

> By default, the virtual machine grows
>   or shrinks the heap at each collection
>   to try to keep the proportion of free
>   space to live objects at each
>   collection within a specific range.
>   This target range is set as a
>   percentage by the parameters
>   -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio= and -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=, and the total size is bounded below by
>   -Xms and above by -Xmx .

Comment: By default in my machine taking 10 gb of maximum heap size because we have 40 gb memory. When i set -Xms15g, what was the maximum size ?

Answer (score 12):

From running java -X:

```
-Xms<size>        set initial Java heap size
-Xmx<size>        set maximum Java heap size
-Xss<size>        set java thread stack size
```

Note that -X options are not guaranteed to exist on all VMs or behave the same on all VMs.  For example -Xms could format your hard drive depending on the VM (it would not - but strictly speaking it could :-) (typing java by itself gives the help with this line: "-X print help on non-standard options").