# Java Out of memory - Out of heap size

Tags: java

I downloaded the sample program , for file transfer between the client and server. When I try running the program with 1 GB file , I get the 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at Client.main(Client.java:31).

Edit:
Line no 31:
byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [FILE_SIZE];

```
public final static int FILE_SIZE = 1097742336;
// receive file
      long startTime = System.nanoTime();
      byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [FILE_SIZE];
      InputStream is = sock.getInputStream();
      fos = new FileOutputStream(FILE_TO_RECEIVED);
      bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
      bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
      current = bytesRead;

      do {
         bytesRead =
            is.read(mybytearray, current, (mybytearray.length-current));
         if(bytesRead >= 0) current += bytesRead;
      } while(bytesRead > -1);

      bos.write(mybytearray, 0 , current);
      bos.flush();
```

Is there any fix for this?

Comment: Well, you are allocating 1GB on the heap.  How big is your JVM heap size set to?

Comment: is this a standalone java program?  Look into -Xmx parameter, to give the program  larger heap size.

Comment: I am seting the -Xmx value to 1 GB , like java -Xmx1000m Client , like that but still I am getting the error

Comment: @Andrew , No I am starting server program in one console, and the one client in another console

Comment: If you set the max heap size to 1gb, you'll still get the error since you have 1gb. Set it to 2gb.

Comment: @user1907849, sorry, I wasn't clear.  I mean are you running it from the command line, as opposed to in Tomcat or such.

Comment: @AnubianNoob: I had tried tried that before itself, by setting 2GB, here is the exception: Could not reserve enough space for 2048000KB object heap

Comment: If you've set the heap to max heap size to 1GB, that isn't enough.  First off, your FILE_SIZE is larger than 1GB (which is 1,073,741,824) bytes.  Second, there are going to be many, many other objects created which will also require space on the heap.

Comment: Then you don't have 2gb of memory available on your computer...

Comment: @Andrew , I am executing in command line itself, since I am not familiar any java tools , I am just 2 days old to java

Comment: What OS are you using? For instance, if you are using Linux, you might need to use the 'ulimit' command to set a higher maximum heap size allowed for a process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you get past your memory allocation woes for this file, the potential for the issue to occur is still there You may want to look into streaming:

```
int count;
byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
while ((count = inStream.read(buffer)) > 0)
{
  outStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, given that you're trying to have a 1gb file in memory, an out of memory error is understandable. Java doesn't have that much memory available for you.

The `-Xmx` flag allows you to set the maximum heap size.

`-Xmx2000m` should be emough.

If you're getting a "Could not reserve enough space" error, that means your computer does not have enough memory available. Try out a smaller file or break the file into small chunks and analyze them one at a time. Or send it as multiple data packets by reading the file in chunks.

Answer (score 1):

You could try setting the Xmx and Xms properties as described here:
[-Xms : Initial heap size or minimum heap size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951347/xms-initial-heap-size-or-minimum-heap-size)

Answer (score 0):

Use the flag -Xmx2G or some value greater than 1G and try again