# Incompatible initial and maximum heap sizes specified

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, nlp

I got this Error when I run a java class which has an NLP library ....

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Incompatible initial and maximum heap sizes specified
```

any idea how i can solve this error :)

Comment: what's the command used to run the java class?

Comment: Bullet point #3 may help: http://javahowto.blogspot.com/2006/06/6-common-errors-in-setting-java-heap.html

Comment: I'm using netbeans to run the java class

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You should note that in case of setting initial heap size bigger than maximum one, application will produce such error

**`-Xms`** means **initial heap size**
**`-Xmx`** means **maximum heap size allowed** for particular JVM

- `java -Xms128m MyClass`

  - WRONG, because default maximum heap size could be lower than 128m
- `java -Xms128m -Xmx128m MyClass`

  - BETTER, because initial size is equal or higher than maximum

Read more here http://javahowto.blogspot.com/2006/06/6-common-errors-in-setting-java-heap.html

And useful is too, to understand those two arguments, read more here if you're interested:

[Speed tradeoff of Java's -Xms and -Xmx options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1043889/492624)
[What are the Xms and Xmx parameters when starting JVMs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763079/what-are-the-xms-and-xmx-parameters-when-starting-jvms)

Comment: I run this command in the dos window java -Xms128m -Xmx128m , but the same error msg comes for me, I am using netbeans ... any idea

Comment: export _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xms128m     fixed my issue

Comment: John's comment above helps me but I nevertheless have to specify the -Xmx parameter: `export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xms1024m -Xmx4048m"`

Answer (score 0):

set **_JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xms128m** in you environment variables, I have attached screenshot for reference. you can set the memeory accordingly.
This happens because JVM was not allocated the memory required.

[image]