# What are the -Xms and -Xmx parameters when starting JVM?

Tags: java, memory-management, parameters, jvm

Please explain the use of the `Xms` and `Xmx` parameters in JVMs. What are the default values for them?

Comment: when using `-Xmx128m -Xms64m` it can peak around `275m` RES mem, but when using `-Xmx128m -Xms128m` it can peak around `550m` RES mem
Using Java 8
Best thing is to stress the GC and look at what happens ...

Comment: Just being curious, the 275m and 550m - How were they calculated?

Comment: Default values see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667483/how-is-the-default-max-java-heap-size-determined

Answer (score 1864, accepted):

The flag `Xmx` specifies the maximum memory allocation pool for a Java Virtual Machine (JVM), while `Xms` specifies the initial memory allocation pool.

This means that your JVM will be started with `Xms` amount of memory and will be able to use a maximum of `Xmx` amount of memory. For example, starting a JVM like below will start it with 256 MB of memory and will allow the process to use up to 2048 MB of memory:

```
java -Xms256m -Xmx2048m
```

The memory flag can also be specified in different sizes, such as kilobytes, megabytes, and so on.

```
-Xmx1024k
-Xmx512m
-Xmx8g
```

The `Xms` flag has no default value, and `Xmx` typically has a default value of 256 MB. A common use for these flags is when you encounter a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`.

When using these settings, keep in mind that these settings are for the JVM's *heap*, and that the JVM can and will use more memory than just the size allocated to the heap. From [Oracle's documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/geninfo/diagnos/garbage_collect.html):

> Note that the JVM uses more memory than just the heap. For example Java methods, thread stacks and native handles are allocated in memory separate from the heap, as well as JVM internal data structures.

Comment: So is it like when memory usage exceeds beyond Xmx we get jvm out of memory exception.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. When it tries to exceed that, although it *may* collect garbage to try to free up enough memory. If there still isn't enough memory to satisfy the request and the heap has already reached the maximum size, an `OutOfMemoryError` will occur.

Comment: When I'm using the ForkJoin framework my computer crashes because it's taking up too much memory. Is it possible that on OpenJDK there is no hard limit on the memory by default?

Comment: As clarified at [Does java -Xmx 1G mean 1 GB or 2^30 B?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32855984/does-java-xmx-1g-mean-1-gb-or-230-b/32858015#32858015), the unambiguous way to express how much memory you start with via `-Xms256m` is "256 MiB", not "256 MB", since it goes by binary powers rather than powers of ten.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix.  In addition, because some unusable space is set aside for an extra pool of Survivor space, the amount of memory actually available according to `Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()` is less than the value specified via -Xmx

Comment: A useful guide of common errors relating to heap size: http://blog.paulgu.com/java/6-common-errors-in-setting-java-heap-size/

Comment: -Xmx8g what does g stand for ?

Comment: "Xmx typically has a default value of 256MB" - very unlikely, that would crash most of the apps - See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667483/how-is-the-default-java-heap-size-determined

Comment: Why I set xmx=xms=8g, my java process does not consume 8g but a much smaller memory when it starts, which I observe from top -->RES. Shouldn't it be allocated by at least the xms memory?

Comment: @Jack I think the 256MB was the default value for Java 6 or 7. Java 8+ uses different default values.

Comment: small precision, it's about the heap (not the stack, not metaspace)

Comment: @David Conrad, I tried the same approach and added Xmx 1GB. Now, I have another two OutOfMemory errors. 

`Java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` and `Java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded`. 

Is this related to Xmx? which I updated to 1GB. I tried with Xmx512 as well but still, it has the same error. Once I start a server after period of time it shows the same error again.

Comment: @ChhaiyaHarshad You should submit a question with details of what your application is doing and the exact command used to start it. It sounds like you have a memory leak.

Comment: This information is no longer up to date: "The Xms flag has no default value, and Xmx typically has a default value of 256 MB". It depends if Java considers the machine to be a client or server, and for servers, Xmx can be up to 32GiB. Take a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/ergonomics.html and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/parallel.html#default_heap_size

Answer (score 415):

Run the command `java -X` and you will get a list of all `-X` options:

```
C:\Users\Admin>java -X
-Xmixed           mixed mode execution (default)
-Xint             interpreted mode execution only
-Xbootclasspath:<directories and zip/jar files separated by ;>
                      set search path for bootstrap classes and resources
-Xbootclasspath/a:<directories and zip/jar files separated by ;>
                      append to end of bootstrap class path
-Xbootclasspath/p:<directories and zip/jar files separated by ;>
                      prepend in front of bootstrap class path
-Xdiag            show additional diagnostic messages
-Xnoclassgc       disable class garbage collection
-Xincgc           enable incremental garbage collection
-Xloggc:<file>    log GC status to a file with time stamps
-Xbatch           disable background compilation
-Xms<size>        set initial Java heap size.........................
-Xmx<size>        set maximum Java heap size.........................
-Xss<size>        set java thread stack size
-Xprof            output cpu profiling data
-Xfuture          enable strictest checks, anticipating future default
-Xrs              reduce use of OS signals by Java/VM (see documentation)
-Xcheck:jni       perform additional checks for JNI functions
-Xshare:off       do not attempt to use shared class data
-Xshare:auto      use shared class data if possible (default)
-Xshare:on        require using shared class data, otherwise fail.
-XshowSettings    show all settings and continue
-XshowSettings:all         show all settings and continue
-XshowSettings:vm          show all vm related settings and continue
-XshowSettings:properties  show all property settings and continue
-XshowSettings:locale      show all locale related settings and continue
```

**The -X options are non-standard and subject to change without notice.**

I hope this will help you understand `Xms`, `Xmx` as well as many other things that matters the most. :)

Answer (score 31):

**-Xms** is the initial heap size for the startup, however, during the working process, the heap size can be less than **-Xms**  due to users' inactivity or GC iterations.
This is not a minimum required heap size.

**-Xmx** is the maximum heap size

Comment: Could you please give more details about "due to users' inactivity or GC iterations"? And what is the difference between initial and minimal heap sizes then?

Comment: I just realized today that `-Xms` doesn't indicate minimum required heap memory size. We are running a java process with `-Xms` set to 200 GB running on a machine with 256 GB RAM. And the process is only consuming 10 GB so far and that's because not much activity was done by the process so far. So, this answer did confirm that but I'm looking to see the documentation/sources about this. thank you so much!

Comment: There are three heap sizes: used, committed, and max. Used heap size can be less than -Xms, but committed heap size (i.e. allocated from the OS via malloc()) is always at least -Xms. Some operating systems will happily malloc() more memory than the have and hope not all applications actually use everything they malloc()ed, so "committed" is a somewhat relative term.

Answer (score 15):

The question itself has already been addressed above. 
Just adding part of the default values.

As per http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/jrdocs/refman/optionX.html

The default value of Xmx will depend on platform and amount of memory available in the system.

Comment: For other JVMs (besides JRockit), see this post to determine default Xmx/Xms values of your JVM: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667483/how-is-the-default-java-heap-size-determined

Answer (score 15):

You can specify it in your IDE. For example, for Eclipse in *Run Configurations* → *VM arguments*. You can enter `-Xmx800m -Xms500m` as

[image]

Comment: In RubyMine on OSX, it's in Help menu > Edit Custom VM Options.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The question is about what they are for, not how to set them.