# Error when starting JBoss EAP-6.3 server with java virtual machine

Tags: java, eclipse, windows, jboss

Hello I have got problem I was reading about some solutions and tried some of them and they helped a little. When i was starting Jboss Developer Studio or Eclipse Luna (32bit) I had error could not create Java Virtual Machine. Then in system environment I added `_JAVA_OPTIONS with New Variable Value: -Xmx512M` and this helped a bit: Now i can run Jboss Developer Studio and Eclipse but when i Start Server in JBoss Developer studio it still gives error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Incompatible minimum and maximum heap sizes specified
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M
```

I dont know how to solve it. I was looking for reason in Internet and trid a few more things but they didnt help.

I will be very thankful for every help.

I have repaired it by adding in System Environment Variables

```
_JAVA_OPTIONS
-Xmx512M -Xms64M -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

And then changing options in `\jbdevstudio\runtimes\jboss-eap-6.3\bin
appclient.conf.bat`

```
rem # JVM memory allocation pool parameters - modify as appropriate.
set "JAVA_OPTS=-Xms64M -Xmx512M -XX:MaxPermSize=512M"
```

Now everything works for me.

Comment: What is the value of `Xms` ? This is the initial heap size, your `Xms` is most likely larger than the max `Xmx` of 512 ...  so set `java -Xms128m -Xmx512m`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Incompatible initial and maximum heap sizes specified](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9350437/incompatible-initial-and-maximum-heap-sizes-specified)

Comment: In C:\users\jbdevstudio\runtimes\jboss-eap-6.3\bin

In appclient.conf.bat
I have:

rem # JVM memory allocation pool parameters - modify as appropriate.
set "JAVA_OPTS=-Xms64M -Xmx512M -XX:MaxPermSize=512M"


In windows -> system environment variables  I added 
_JAVA_OPTIONS
-Xmx512M
If i delete this then i cant even start eclipse/jboss dev studio with this i can start them

Comment: Removed wrong tag "virtualmachine"