# Minecraft forge automatically sets _JAVA_OPTIONS environment variable

Tags: java, environment-variables, minecraft-forge

I just started making minecraft mods and everything went fine until I ran the program (`minecraft forge 1.12.2`). It said:

```
Initial heap size set to a larger value than the maximum heap size can  
after that: picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M  
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Using incremental CMS is deprecated and will likely be removed in a future release.
```

When I checked my environment vraiables, I found `_JAVA_OPTIONS` and deleted it, but the problem remains, What should I do?

I am on a Windows 10 computer and have 8 GB ram.

Comment: Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9350437/incompatible-initial-and-maximum-heap-sizes-specified. Most likely setting minimum heap size (`-Xms512M`, for example) will help.

Comment: thand you, it worked!

Comment: Nice to hear, could you then post the exact instruction of what you've done as an answer and accept it?

Answer (score 0):

```
Initial heap size set to a larger value than the maximum heap size can
```

Means that the maximum heap size is smaller than the initial heap size.
To solve this problem simply add _JAVA_OPTIONS and set it to
`-Xmx512M -Xms512M`.
`-Xms512M` Just sets the initial heap size to 512mb.